# Flex Mobile List

Tags: android, asp.net, flash-builder, flex-mobile

Is there a way to use a Flex Mobile List control like a ASP.NET repeater? 
For example a repeater in ASP.NET allows you to have many controls in the itemtemplate that can be bound to a data source. A easier way to understand it is using the Facebook mobile application. I'm wondering how that is created because I can't seem to use a grid or a list to  function in that way.

Comment: A screenshot of what you want may help here.  I don't know anything about an ASP.NET repeater or the Facebook mobile application.  You may want to look into using an itemRendererFunction to display items in a list differently; but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Do you know any good tutorial's for the itemRenderer function? I wasn't able to find any that we're able to explain it well enough. I checked YouTube, Google, and even Adobe's website.

Comment: Just add a picture of what you're trying to do here with some additional information, otherwise it'll be nearly impossible to give you any recommendations, yet specific coding assistance.

Comment: Google for Flex itemRendererFunction and some things come up. http://blog.flexexamples.com/tag/itemrendererfunction/ or http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS77c1dbb1bd80d3836ecbb5ec129ec77b1e1-8000.html#WS94F31173-40D5-4ddd-B7B3-17D02BD57EAF

Answer (score 1):

Although I have never used ASP.NET repeaters, I believe you are referring to an ItemRenderer. Each item in the list will display differently, depending on the data provided to it. You can write your own ItemRenderer in either ActionScript or MXML. If you have large and/or complex data in the list, I would recommend using ActionScript. They can be a little tricky at first, but you will get the hang of it. Start out small. Try simply extending a LabelItemRenderer and setting the text value based on the the data object, then expand it from there. Be sure to take a look at some of the great documentation for it [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-fc6548e124e49b51c4-8000.html), and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS684a1733bf2efe8a3a0afb75129d7657f1c-7fff.html).